# Find particular lines and wrap them with <b>

Tags: php, regex

I want to wrap particular lines in a text mass with `<b></b>`

- First line in the text
- All lines with a previous empty line (eg two newlines before)

I'm using preg_replace with php, but I'm really shitty with regex. Good tutorials are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
echo preg_replace('/(?<=\\A|^$\n)(^.+$)/m', '<b>$1</b>', $text);
```

for example, http://www.ideone.com/1pTwD.

Comment: Great! And that link can prove to be very useful as well. Many thanks man! Appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In HTML (I'm assuming that's the context) there is no such thing as "lines" in regards to source code, since it's not really possible reliable to determinate how a text wraps (unless you do all the wrapping yourself with `<br>` or `<pre>`).

However there is the CSS pseudo-element `:first-line` that will let you format the first line of an element (for example a paragraph):

```
p:first-line {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Actually I know how the lines are formated since the text is pasted from an In-Design document. The text need to have the <b> tags in place due to the customers needs.

Comment: Indesign is a Desktop Publishing software. For publishing on paper. **The web is not paper**. Unless you are using a screen shot you can't grantee the text to wrap the same on the web. Do you actually need `b` tags or does the first line need to be bold?